# Does Tor protect against KRACK?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, orbot, network-configuration

I am using a wifi connection I don't control, on a device that hasn't yet received a KRACK patch. Will Tor [1] protect my browsing data if the wifi connection is compromised? (Is there anything that won't be protected?)

[1] and Tor Browser Bundle, or Orbot and Orfox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Tor is unaffected by KRACK.

At best KRACK could be used to perform some denial of service (stopping your packets from being sent), but it will not be able to forge or intercept Tor traffic, since it is end-to-end crypted before it is sent over the network.

Assuming you have a good copy of Tor (you both verified it's signed by the correct key and that the key is valid) then no kind of man-in-the-middle attack can be performed on your connection into or across the Tor network (although it can be performed on traffic leaving the network).

Answer (score 2):

You're using wifi with a wireless access point that you don't control and you're worried about KRACK? If the owner of the access point wanted access to your network data then KRACK doesn't matter.

Anyways, according to the latest KRACK details BOTH the client and access point need to be updated to mitigate it. It's an attack on the wifi connection so it's not like it affects applications aside from letting an attacker break into that connection (which you should already be worried about since it's not your WAP).

Comment: that's an interesting point, that if someone diverts you from a WAP you don't control to another WAP you don't control, the threat is similar (although it's more likely that the diverter has active bad intent)